# JTable TableModel problem in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I can show my data in a `JTable` without a problem, but when I want to filter while my app is running, the `JTable` is not showing me data changes. I searched for it and found a class named TableModel but I can't write my AbstractTableModel. Can anyone show me how I can do this?

Personelz.Java

```
package deneme.persistence;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
 *
 * @author İbrahim AKGÜN
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONELZ", catalog = "tksDB", schema = "dbo")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Personelz.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Personelz p"), @NamedQuery(name = "Personelz.findByPersonelıd", query = "SELECT p FROM Personelz p WHERE p.personelıd = :personelıd"), @NamedQuery(name = "Personelz.findByAd", query = "SELECT p FROM Personelz p WHERE p.ad = :ad"), @NamedQuery(name = "Personelz.findBySoyad", query = "SELECT p FROM Personelz p WHERE p.soyad = :soyad")})
public class Personelz implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PERSONELID", nullable = false )
    private Integer personelıd;
    @Column(name = "AD", length = 50)
    private String ad;
    @Column(name = "SOYAD", length = 50)
    private String soyad;
    @Column(name = "YAS")
    private Integer yas;
    public Personelz() {
    }

    public Personelz(Integer personelıd) {
        this.personelıd = personelıd;
    }

    public Integer getPersonelıd() {
        return personelıd;
    }

    public void setPersonelıd(Integer personelıd) {
        this.personelıd = personelıd;
    }

    public String getAd() {
        return ad;
    }

    public void setAd(String ad) {
        String oldAd = this.ad;
        this.ad = ad;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("ad", oldAd, ad);
    }

    public String getSoyad() {
        return soyad;
    }

    public void setSoyad(String soyad) {
        String oldSoyad = this.soyad;
        this.soyad = soyad;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("soyad", oldSoyad, soyad);
    }
     public Integer getYas() {
        return yas;
    }
public void setYas(Integer yas){
this.yas = yas;

}
```

TABLEMODEL

```
 public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

String[] headers;
List<Personelz> personel;
int row;
int column;
Object[][] per;
/** Creates a new instance of TableModel */
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
public TableModel(List<Personelz> p) {

    this.personel = p;
    column=2;
    row=this.personel.size();

    headers=new String[column];
    headers[0]="AD";
    headers[1]="SOYAD";
    per={p.toArray(),p.toArray()};

}

 public int getColumnCount()
 {
     return column;
 }
 public int getRowCount()
 {
     return row;
 }
 public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int kolonindex)
 {

     return per[rowIndex][kolonindex];
 }
 public String getColumnName(int i)
 {
     return headers[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest reading this [How to Use Tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire) (from the Java Tutorials Using Swing Components)

Basically the TableModel has to notify the Table of changed data by firing the appropriate Events. See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire)

Comment: jitter is correct. The JTable listens to the TableModel. The TableModel fires TableModelEvent to its listener when its state has changed. You can extend AbstractTableModel or use DefaultTableModel which has some support for managing the listeners and firing the events.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good library called GlazedLists that makes it a lot simpler to work with lists and tables, including column sorting and row filtering.

Its definitely worth taking a look.

http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize the `TableModelListener` interface, which your `JTable` implements.  Once you add your table to your TableModel, call the appropriate `fireTableChanged()`-type event that `AbstractTableModel` implements.  This should force your `JTable` to update.

You will still need to implement a method to reset your data in your model when your filter operation returns.  it should be in this method that you call your `fireTableChanged()` event.  you also should ensure that you are in the AWT thread when you fire the table changed event.